# Custom Button that mass updates fields in an Object (APEX)

Tags: apex, visualforce

I am literally new in APEX, I am originally a SF Admin.

SO this is my 1st APEX project.

I would like to mass update the values of a date field in an Object.

Can someone give me a sample how to do it?

I really appreciate your help on this.

Thanks !

Comment: Do you want to be able to input a date and mass update that input value?  Or mass update from a certain field...?

Comment: something like changing the date value to today everytime the button is clicked or either changed text field to NULL.

Comment: I am really new so reading through complex codes online really confuses me. So I would like to start on this simple task and I will take it from here. Appreciate your time on this Sir @NathanWilliams.

Comment: How many records are we talking about? If you want to update 10,000 or more you will need to use batch Apex.

Comment: About less than 10-20 records. Just a start code for me to reference with. Thanks @DanielBallinger

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you take a look at the recipes in the Force.com cookbook. You can download it [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/JP%3aForce_Platform_Cookbook)

what you want to do is likely most easily done using a list view button. A complete recipe is available in the downloadable cookbook, plus a heap of other resources you are likely to find useful. Happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

**On the controller:**

```
public void updateMyAccounts() {
   Object__c[] objs = [SELECT id, Custom_Date_Field__c FROM Object__c WHERE CreatedDate = TODAY];
   for (Object__c obj : objs) {
   obj.Custom_Date_Field__c = date.today();
}
update objs;
}
```

**On the Visualforce page:**

```
<apex:commandButton value="Update Dates" action="{!updateMyAccounts}"/>
```

This is a very, very basic example you can work off of. Here's what's going on:

You are creating a method to be called from the Visualforce page called "updateMyAccounts". First in the method, you are creating a list of Object__c records by running a query. The query I wrote simply grabs only the info you need for this example: the id of the record and the Custom_Date_Field__c for each record. I added a filter to only select records "WHERE CreatedDate = TODAY" just as an example of a filter you can add to narrow which records you want to mass update. Keep in mind pulling back 10,000+ records will error out when updating. Next you enter a for loop to iterate through the list and assign today's date to the Custom_Date_Field__c for each record. Then you will update the entire list to save the changes to the date field.

In your Visualforce page you will create a button that can be pressed and when it is, the method above will run and all the records will be updated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use data loader too for mass updates